# Graphic not showing in GUI - Java

Tags: java, jframe

I don't want to make a repeat question as I have found many things similar, but nothing that is working for me. This is my first time using JFrame and I have followed a tutorial, word for word, and in my program, my line does not appear on the screen. I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. Could someone please take a look and let me know what I need to change? Again, I am completely new to this.

Here is the code, thank you :)

```
package simplepaint;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class SimplePaint extends JFrame {

public void Paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawLine(0, 480, 960, 480);
    g.drawLine(342, 283, 384, 238);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Let's Paint!");
    window.setSize(960,960); //600, 480
    window.setLocation(100,100);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    window.setVisible(true);

   }    

}
```

Comment: In your research did you come across any Stack Overflow questions or answers that stated not to directly draw on a `JFrame`? Your `Paint` method isn't being called by the `JFrame` because you're not overriding the right method, it should be `paint`. (note that you shouldn't override `paint`, you should instead override `paintComponent`)

Comment: No, I just started trying to learn this yesterday. Here is the tutorial I am currently following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7YbQrrcpAQ

Comment: Thank you! That really helped! :)